# How to get all variables with pattern in name into a list while inside function

Tags: r

I have a function like the following one, which generates various variables with similar names. While inside this function, I want to get all of the variables into a list. I know this example doesn't seem very efficient, as I could use lists from the first place, but in my function it is necessary I do this.

```
test_function <- function(x) {
    myenv <- new.env()
    myenv$hello1 = "hello1string"
    myenv$hello2 = "hello2string"
    myenv$cello2 = "hello2string"
    mylist <- lapply(ls(name = myenv, pattern = "hello"), get)
    print(class(mylist))
}
```

How do I get all of the variables starting with "hello" into a list without it giving the error:  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'hello1' not found when running `test_function()`. This even happens when putting the variables into a shared environment.

I would like the final `mylist` to be of class list, not character.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an environment and then create variables inside it. Then using `ls()` function with the environment name and the correct pattern, you can see the list of variables in the environment that matches the given pattern.

```
test_function <- function(x) {
  myenv <- new.env()
  myenv$hello1 = "hello1"
  myenv$hello2 = "hello2"
  myenv$cello2 = "hello2"
  mylist <- ls(name = myenv, pattern = "hello")
  print(mylist)
}
test_function(1)
# [1] "hello1" "hello2"
```

You can use `mget` to extract values for a list of variables inside an environment.

```
test_function <- function(x, y, z, pattern) {
  myenv <- new.env()
  ls_vars <- list( hello1 = x,
                   hello2 = y,
                   cello2 = z)
  list2env( ls_vars, myenv )   # add list of variables to myenv environment
  newvar <- "hello3"
  assign(newvar, value = "dfsfsf", envir = myenv)  # assign new variable
  mylist <- ls(name = myenv, pattern = pattern)
  return(mget(mylist, envir = myenv))
}
test_function(x = "hello1", y = "hello2", z = "sdfsd", pattern = "hello")
# $hello1
# [1] "hello1"
# 
# $hello2
# [1] "hello2"
# 
# $hello3
# [1] "dfsfsf"

test_function(x = "hello1", y = "hello2", z = "sdfsd", pattern = "cello")
# $cello2
# [1] "sdfsd"
```

Comment: Is there a way to put all variables generated by that function into an environment without manually changing all of the variable assignments? Manually changing the variable names would not be possible because I use `assign(paste(xxx), yyy)` to generate many of my variables which change name based on the inputs.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that I cannot individually go through and assign all of the variables to an environment. I was wondering whether it was possible to add something to the beginning of the function to somehow force things to the assigned environment (or even global environment) so that getting the variables into a list is easier. In your initial response, `mylist` is of class character, but I need it to be of class list. Please feel free to ask any questions if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Even if I use your initial response and assign environment, I still get the error when using lapply to get the variables into a list. `test_function <- function(x) {
    myenv <- new.env()
    myenv$hello1 = "hello1"
    myenv$hello2 = "hello2"
    myenv$cello2 = "hello2"
    mylist <- lapply(ls(name = myenv, pattern = "hello"), get)
    print(class(mylist))
}`

Comment: I think my last statement `print(mylist)` might have made it unclear that I wanted the output as class list. Sorry about that.

Comment: do you want variables with values from the environment?

Comment: That gives me a list of only the variable names, not the actual variables themselves. How would I get a list of the actual variables? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want! A list of the variables with values from the environment.